# Navigate inside Modal

Tags: ios, user-interface, nativescript, user-experience

In the `Instagram` app on iOS you'll notice that when you logout, a `modal` pops up for signing in. If you click on `signup` then the page transition occurs inside that modal.

How could I achieve the same flow with `nativescript`?

Comment: Not supported at this moment - marked as feature here: https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/3753

Answer (score 1):

You will need to call `topmost().navigate()` to navigate to your landing page on clicking the login button, you will also need to make a call to `closeCallback()` to hide the modal page.
This snippet might help -

On clicking the logout:

```
page.showModal("logoutModal", context, function(data){
       console.log("Displaying Logout Modal");
}, fullscreenBoolean);
```

On clicking Login or some other button on modal:

```
export function moveTo() {
  var navigationEntry = {
     moduleName: "landingPage"
  }
  frame.topmost().navigate(navigationEntry);
  closeCallback();
}
```

For more information: https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/3308

I just used the above code it worked fine for me.

Comment: I don't want to hide the modal. I just want to continue the navigation inside the modal. (i.e) If I have a `login` page in a modal then clicking on the `Signup` option shouldn't close the login modal and go to the signup page instead the signup page should be pushed into the modal's navigation stack

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.
Nativescript team had a feature request for this but I am not sure if they got it working. You can look into:
[Github question](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-angular/issues/603)
[Feature Request](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/3753)